# how to use character pointer for string?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

please help me with this

i tried getting a string through char * and gets()
it doesnt give any compile time error but it throws run time error segmentation fault.
but if i give

char *s="sample";

its working fine

anyone could explain me

```
int main()
{
    char *s,*r;
    printf("enter\n");
    gets("pavithra");
    scanf("%s",r);
    printf("%s",s);
    printf("%s",r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for "gets()". "man gets" should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: In addition to the call to gets() being wrong, the pointers s and r have been created, but are not actually pointing at any memory.  Attempting to use scanf or printf on them is undefined behaviour, and will probably crash.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char *s,*r;
   printf("enter\n");
   gets(s);
   scanf("%s",r);
   printf("%s\n",s);
   printf("%s\n",r); 
   return 0;
}
```

Reason:
You can't initialize the character pointer s in gets(),function gets() takes a input string from the user,thus s doesn't got initialized in your code.